# prevent XFCE from showing display settings on laptop lid close/open

Tags: xfce, display-settings

When I close or open my laptop lid, xfce executes *xfce4-display-settings --minimal*. I want to make that stop, but how? I found nothing in the settings under */etc/xdg/xfce4* and *.config/xfce4*.

Answer (score 2):

The hardware triggers such as lid closing/opening can be interpreted and managed by your Desktop Environment, but since you cannot find anything related in Xfce configuration, it could mean they are handled in a generic way - by the **`acpid`** daemon. Look into the files under `/etc/acpi/`. You can grep for "lid" there (run `grep -iR lid /etc/acpi/`).

Answer (score 1):

1. Run `$ xfce4-keyboard-settings`   as a regular user
2. Choose "Application shortcuts"
3. Delete the following line:

   "xfce4-display-settings --minimal XF86Display"